# What does One True Language mean in programming context?

Tags: programming-languages

Seriously, what does it mean (I'm confused as a newbie)?

Comment: It's synonymous with "my favorite programming language".

Comment: Gotcha. Appreciate the quick replies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's used, often comically, to present a favoritism bordering (or long past) the level of religious belief and fanaticism towards the superiority of a specific language.

For example, "Python is the One True Language" would roughly mean "I strongly prefer Python for most situations and I don't mind showing a bit of fanaticism about it".  When applied to another, it could be used in the previous sense or derogatorily: "for him, Python is the One True Language" roughly meaning "even when it's not the right tool for the job at hand, he'll try to force a solution in Python".

Comment: Appreciate the quick replies.

Answer (score 1):

**It really doesn't mean anything**, at least not anything useful.

Perhaps the best definition is that it's the language preferred by the speaker, and the one they egotistically think everyone else should prefer, too. This is because they perceive their individual preference for the language as indicative of its inherent superiority.

You could also interpret it as an expression of the speaker's failure to understand the need to use the right tool for the job. If all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail.

As a newbie, your best bet is to learn a particular language of your choosing and general programming concepts really well, then branch out into different languages and architectures. Ignore the bigots.